# How to plot a histogram of already summarized data in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I have an array of 100 elements. The index of the array is a percentage value, and the value of the array[index] is the amount of items with that percentage. I need a histogram where the x axis is the index ordered asc, and the y axis is the value.

But when I use the hist function, is summarizes the data, like doing a group by in SQL of the value column, and the graph is not what I need.

How can I achieve this in R?